# php number format in table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a little problem.
I use the html table shape as the output in the php query. I want to use the x.xxx,xx shape for the inventory total field. however, numberformat did not work.

how do I do it .?

**number_format({$item['stok_toplam']}) is not work .**

```html
<?php
    try
    {

        $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.15.153,1433;Database=MikroDB_V16_2021", 'user', 'password');
 
        
        $data = $db -> query("SELECT msg_S_0014, msg_S_0785, sum(msg_S_0165) as stok_toplam FROM STOKLAR_YONETIM_Mobile where msg_S_0001 LIKE 's%' group by msg_S_0014,msg_S_0785 order by msg_S_0014")->fetchAll();
    
        //Kayıt sayısı ekrana bastırılacak.
        echo count($data)."</br>"."</br>";

        foreach ($data as $item)

        echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0 >
<tr>  <td style='color:green' width=150px>$item[msg_S_0014]</td><td style width=150px>$item[msg_S_0785]<td style width=150px align=right>$item[stok_toplam]</font></td></tr> 

</table>";

    }
    catch (Exception $exception)
    {
        //Eğer bağlantı sırasında bir hata oluşursa ekrana oluşan hata bastırılacaktır.
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: what does `$item[stok_toplam]` give you, and what do you need? also, you should use quotes around `stok_toplam`, because otherwise php thinks that you're trying to reference a constant.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/MOE71EqkwTbE.png  That's the result. 29.914,50 as needed. number_format($sayı)  or number_format($sayı, 2, ',', '.')  not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use single quotes to define the array offset.
Define the variables, then echo them to html. Or use template tags. Like this:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0 >
<tr>  <td style='color:green' width=150px>{$item['msg_S_0014']}</td><td style width=150px>{$item['msg_S_0785']}<td style width=150px align=right>{$item['stok_toplam']}</font></td></tr> 

</table>";
}
```

Comment: My code works as above. I just need to get (29.914,50 as needed.) number_format($sayı) or number_format($sayı, 2, ',', '.')  working.

Comment: number format({$item['stok_toplam']})  is not work  ..

Answer (score 0):

**I edited it as follows. it's working fine.**

```html
foreach ($data as $item) {
        $para = number_format($item['stok_toplam'], 0, ',', '.');
echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0 >
<tr>  <td style='color:green' width=150px>{$item['msg_S_0014']}</td><td style width=150px>{$item['msg_S_0785']}<td style width=150px align=right>{$para}</font></td></tr> 

</table>";
}
```